# Conditional Statement Continues After Attempting to Exit in PySide6 GUI

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside6

I am using PySide6 to create a GUI and wanting to add a button that when pressed aborts the program but does not close the main window just stops the current code that is running. I have done my best to strip down the GUI to be as simple as possible, but still illustrates the point at hand.

Here is the code:

```py
import sys
import time

from PySide6.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QGridLayout,
    QTableView, QHeaderView, QPushButton, QMessageBox,
)
from PySide6.QtGui import QCursor, QBrush
from PySide6.QtCore import QSize, Qt

from table_model import TableModel


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    '''
    Main Window GUI
    '''
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowTitle("Start and Abort Question")
        self.setFixedSize(QSize(900, 525))
        
        self.create_table()

        self.start_button = QPushButton("Start Test", self)
        self.start_button.clicked.connect(self.click_start)
        self.start_button.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))

        layout = QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.table, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.start_button, 1, 0)

        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

    def create_table(self):
        '''
        Creates table
        '''

        self.table = QTableView()
        h_header = self.table.horizontalHeader()
        h_header.setVisible(False)
        h_header.setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)
        v_header = self.table.verticalHeader()
        v_header.setVisible(False)

        data = [
            ["Task 1"],
            ["Task 2"],
            ["Task 3"],
            ["Task 4"],
            ["Task 5"],
            ["Task 6"],
            ["Task 7"],
            ["Task 8"]
        ]

        self.model = TableModel(data)
        self.table.setModel(self.model)

    def click_start(self):
        '''
        When start button is clicked program runs
        '''

        keep_running = True

        while keep_running == True:
            # Test 1
            if self.start_button.text() == "Start Test":
                self.start_button.setText("Abort Test")
                QApplication.processEvents()
                for i in range(8):
                    self.model.setData(self.model.index(i, 0), QBrush(Qt.green), Qt.BackgroundRole)
                    QApplication.processEvents()
                    time.sleep(0.5)
                keep_running = False

            elif self.start_button.text() == "Abort Test":

                msg = QMessageBox()
                msg.setIcon(msg.Warning)
                msg.setText("Test Aborted!")
                msg.addButton(msg.Ok)
                msg.setDefaultButton(msg.Ok)
                msg.exec()
                keep_running = False

        # Button Changes back
        self.start_button.setText("Start Test")

# Needed per applicaiton
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setStyle('Fusion')
# Displays main windows
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
# Starts the loop
app.exec()
```

Right now, the GUI is just a window with a button. When the start button is pressed the text changes to say, "Abort Test". When start is pressed the code will run and change the color of the rows of the table. When I press "Abort Test" the QMessageBox will pop up. **The problem occurs** when I close the QMessageBox the program that was running when I first clicked start will continue to color rows of the table instead of stopping. I have tried putting the code in the `click_start` function inside a while loop and using the `break` statement but get the same results.

This section of code is the Table Model that I created as a separate python file table_model.py and import into the code above.

```py
'''
Table Model
'''

from PySide6.QtCore import (
    Qt, QAbstractTableModel
)
from PySide6.QtGui import QFont


class TableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    '''
    Table Model
    '''

    def __init__(self, data):
        super().__init__()
        self._data = data
        rows = len(data)
        cols = len(data[0])
        self._backgrounds = [[None] * cols for _ in range(rows)]

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if not index.isValid():
            return

        elif role in (Qt.DisplayRole, Qt.EditRole):
            return self._data[index.row()][index.column()]

        elif role == Qt.BackgroundRole:
            return self._backgrounds[index.row()][index.column()]

        elif role == Qt.TextAlignmentRole:
            return Qt.AlignCenter

        elif role == Qt.FontRole:
            font = QFont("72 Black")
            return font

    def setData(self, index, value, role=Qt.EditRole):
        if (
            not index.isValid()
            or index.row() >= len(self._data)
            or index.column() >= len(self._data[0])
        ):
            return False

        if role == Qt.EditRole:
            self._data[index.row()][index.column()] = value
        elif role == Qt.BackgroundRole:
            self._backgrounds[index.row()][index.column()] = value
        else:
            return False

        self.dataChanged.emit(index, index, [role])
        return True

    def rowCount(self, index):
        # The length of the outer list.
        return len(self._data)

    def columnCount(self, index):
        # The following takes the first sub-list, and returns
        # the length (only works if all rows are an equal length)
        return len(self._data[0])
```

I am convinced this is a very trivial task, but nothing that I do seems actually stop the program.

Comment: You cannot "stop code" from executing, unless you put periodic checks that could eventually allow it. I suppose that you want to interrupt whatever happens in place of that `time.sleep()`, but without knowing what that actually is, we cannot help you. You should provide a [mre] that includes that part.

Comment: I have updated the question to include more complete example of what I am trying to "stop"

Comment: Just create a basic bool attribute (eg. `self.keepRunning = True`), change it to `False` when you want to stop it, and check it at every iteration of the for loop.

Comment: @musicamante following your suggestions I added my code in a while loop that runs as long as `keep_running` is True. However, even after I press the "Abort Test" and `keep_running` is set to False once the popup close the coloring of the rows continues.

Comment: 1. Don't use a while loop in the main indentation level of the function; 2. I explicitly wrote to create an *attribute*, **not** a variable: `self.keepRunning`.